# How to get login and pass from rest request in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm writing REST app with spring boot and spring security with JWT.

I created registration end point which just creates an account.

I wanted to implement authentication througn basic auth with login and password which would returns a jwt token. Other requests would authenticate by token.

But I can't implement security by login and password and JWT both, so I tried to perform basic auth manually and leave spring security by token.

How can I get login and password from rest request in controller to check if the account exists in the database manyally?

The example of basic auth:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT token is an string joined by points. It has three pieces and these are encoded in base64. The second piece has the information of the user. You can pass this information to the security context and get wherever you want.

Decode the token, set the information in UserDetails (you can extend this class) and pass it to the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. Pass this object to the security context and get the information in your controllers using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

More info here: https://www.toptal.com/spring/spring-security-tutorial

```
// Get user identity and set it on the spring security context
        UserDetails userDetails = userRepo
            .findByUsername(jwtTokenUtil.getUsername(token))
            .orElse(null);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
            authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userDetails, null,
                userDetails == null ?
                    List.of() : userDetails.getAuthorities()
            );

        authentication.setDetails(
            new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but it's not related with the question. Sorry for confusion with token, it would be better if I didn't write about jwt at all. My question is how to get login and password from basic auth data in a controller without jwt and without spring security

Comment: did you try to read the header and decode the value?

Comment: I found the solution, your idea about decoding the header was correct

Answer (score -1):

Basic auth and JWT are so different. Basic authenticatio requires that you send the username and password joined by : and encoded in base64. JWT requires a service (may be external like firebase auth or internal in your spring boot) that generates the JWT token. The JWT token should be passed in Authorization header.

Read this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248195/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-jwt-over-basic-auth-with-https

Comment: As I wrote in the post I will use JWT with spring security for all requests and I have already implemented JWT auth, basic auth is only needed for login request to generate and get the token and will be writen manually. I have only one question: how can I get login and password in the controller from basic auth when user makes login request?

Comment: You can make use of UserDetails and UserDetailsService method loadUserByUsername(), which is hit when authenticaion attempt is made and you can get id and password from this method after login attempt.